# How to write transparent image to clipboard in Electron

Tags: electron

I have tried to use [clipboard.writeImage()](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/clipboard#clipboardwriteimageimage-type) to write a [nativeImage](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/native-image) with transparency into clipboard. But after I paste the image, its transparent part turns into black. So how can I write the image correctly?

Environment: Windows 10, Node v8.11.3, Electron 2.0.2

Answer (score 0):

This is not Electron bug. Windows clipboard, by default, does not support transparency.

[Copying From and To Clipboard loses image transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44177115/copying-from-and-to-clipboard-loses-image-transparency)